# Keras: Adding batch of constant inputs to Dense Layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I have a neural network with two different inputs. Input 1 is image data and Input 2 is a single float. So my input is of shape `(32,img_dim)` and `(32,1)` for a batch size of 32.

The NN's output layer is a Dense layer with 10+ (can vary) outputs with a linear activation function (Regression). I would like to add the float in Input 2 to each of the 10+ outputs. How can I add a simple value (different for each sample in the batch) to a whole layer (broadcast it to 10+ outputs).

e.g. for a batch size of 3 I have Input 2:

```
[12.0,23.0,60.0]
```

Now I want to add `12.0` for the first sample to all units in the layer. Then `23.0` for the next sample in the batch  and so  on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functional API Model

```
from keras.models import Model
```

Make two inputs for the model:

```
inpImg = Input((rows,columns,channels))
inpFloat = Input((1,))
```

Create your layers like this:

```
outputTensor = SomeLayer(....)(inputTensor)

#example:
convOut = Conv2D(20,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(inpImg)
```

At the point you want the multiplication, we create a Lambda layer for a custom operation (suppose you have `lastOut` from your last layer). Notice this layer is taking two inputs in a list, that's why we need the functional API model.

```
multOut = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1],output_shape=(10,))([lastOut,inpFloat])
```

Then, create the model:

```
model = Model([inpImg,inpFloat],multOut)
```

Compile the model normally, and when fitting and predicting, pass a list of numpy inputs:

```
model.fit([trainImages, trainFloats],labels)
```